# Why is my service not being loaded correctly only in one of my controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I've built my personal website with the MEAN stack and built a backend with an online MongoDB to store all my site's content. I then created a service in angular named 'contentService' to grab all the content via the API. I have 5 pages on my website, and on 4/5, the Content loads properly when I inject my 'contentService' into the controllers.

However, on this one specific controller, 'portfolioController', when I try to inject the 'Content', none of the data gets through. I even did a console.log on all the different pages, and this is the only one where data isn't showing up in my console. Also getting the error, 'Content.all is not a function', because it's not getting through.

Obviously I'm injecting it incorrectly somehow, but I've tried rearranging and can't find the right combo. What's the issue here?

Example of controller that is loading service properly -

```
angular.module('aboutCtrl', ['contentService'])

.controller('aboutController', function(Content) {

  var vm = this;

  Content.all()
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.paragraphOne = data[0].aboutParagraphs[0].paragraph;
      vm.paragraphTwo = data[0].aboutParagraphs[1].paragraph;
      vm.profiles = data[0].socialMediaProfiles;
    });

  vm.firstParagraph = true;

  vm.switchParagraph = function() {
    vm.firstParagraph = false;
  };

});
```

The code that isn't loading the Content Properly -

```
angular.module('portfolioCtrl', ['ui.bootstrap', 'contentService'])

.controller('portfolioController', ['filterFilter', '$modal',        function(Content, filterFilter, $modal) {

  var vm = this;

  Content.all()
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.schools = data[0].languages;
      vm.companies = data[0].projects;
    });

  vm.carouselInterval = 3000;
  vm.noWrapSlides = false;

  vm.projectsToShow = vm.projects;

  vm.projectSort = function(language) {
    vm.projectsToShow = vm.projects;

    switch (language.reference) {

      case 'all':
        vm.projectsToShow;
        break;

      case 'angular':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'angular');
        break;

      case 'node':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'node');
        break;

      case 'ruby':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'ruby');
        break;

      default:
        vm.projectsToShow;
    };
  };

  vm.selectedProject;

  vm.openProject = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/portfolioModal.html',
      controller: 'modalCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'modal',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        project: function() {
          return vm.selectedProject;
        }
      }
    });
  };

}])

.controller('modalCtrl', ['$modalInstance', 'project',     function($modalInstance, project) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.selectedProject = project;

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your injector array is missing the `Content` variable. All dependencies must be listed there if you choose to use that syntax.

```
.controller('portfolioController', ['Content', 'filterFilter', '$modal',          
    function(Content, filterFilter, $modal) {
        ...
}])
```

Aside: you shouldn't use the injector array syntax. It's very error prone and it's only required if you are minifying your code. And if you are minifying, you should use [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) anyway to handle dependency notation.

Comment: Also, they need to be in the same order.

Comment: @jtbitt You should try to stick with a syntax for readability.  Also if you add obfuscation you need to use the syntax above.

Comment: Aha! I tried this last night but they weren't in order and it didn't work. It's working now! 

@Malkus when you say syntax do you mean using syntax more similar to the answer above, instead of all on one line?

Comment: Yes the **inline array annotation** is the preferred method.  Which is the format in the answer `['depA',function(depA) {...}]` [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)